# Ethereum beacon chain node (Lighthouse) fails to connect to GoEthereum

Tags: go-ethereum, beacon-chain, lighthouse

Ethereum beacon chain node (e.g. Lighthouse) fails to connect to GoEthereum execution layer node with the error seen in GoEthereum logs:

```
the method engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 does not exist/is not available
```

Or as seen in Lighthouse logs:

```
 Sep 07 09:20:35.719 WARN Error connecting to eth1 node endpoint  action: trying fallbacks, endpoint: http://vitalik.example.com:8551/, auth=true, service: deposit_contract_rpc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any beacon chain node needs [Engine JSON-RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-apis/tree/main/src/engine) available it to co-ordinate between consensus layer (beacon chain) and execution layer (GoEthereum). Normally the Engine API is exposed over special JSON-RPC endpoint that is called `authrpc` in GoEthereum. It does [JWT token authentication](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-apis/blob/main/src/engine/authentication.md) for any request.

Make sure that

- You have authrpc turned on in GoEthereum
- You pass this special endpoint as `--execution-endpoint` to [Lighthouse](https://github.com/sigp/lighthouse) (or similar beacon chain node), as opposite to normal JSON-RPC API endpoint
- Both share the same JWT token

Here is the example of GoEthereum command line arguments, assuming we want to connect to our node using JSON-RPC URL `http://vitalik.example.com:8551`:

```
        --authrpc.jwtsecret=/jwtsecret
        --authrpc.port 8551
        --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0 
        --authrpc.vhosts=vitalik.example.com
```

Here are the matching Lighthouse command line arguments:

```
      --jwt-secret=/jwtsecret
      --execution-endpoint=http://vitalik.example.com:8551
```

A JWT secret can be generated using [OpenSSL command line helper command](https://www.openssl.org/):

```
openssl rand -hex 32 > ./jwtsecret
```

Then share this file between Lighthouse and GoEthereum. **Note that the JWT file contents might be newline sensitive**, so make sure you do not mess up the ending newline if you manually copy-paste the contents around.

Note: As far as I know, there is no easy way to test if authrpc or JWT token based authentication works with tools like `curl`. At the moment the option is to test it just by restarting your beacon chain node and see if it connects or not to your GoEthereum node. You can still test if the endpoint replies:

```shell
curl http://vitalik2.example.com:8551 \              
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"engine_getPayloadV1","params": ["0x1"],"id":1}'
```

```
missing token
```